# PHP hide username and password from webhook

Tags: php, email, authentication, passwords, webhooks

I am new to using web-hooks and am trying to 
send an email when the hook is requested.
API data will be sent to the PHP Webhook 
where it will send the email to the appropriate 
patron provided by the API.

Here is my issue. The API data that is sent to
the web-hook for processing includes the name of the admin who 
initiated the action. I have the email portion of this working
if i set the user credential in the script which is not safe. 
The password to the admin's email is needed to authenticate 
before sending an email. I would like to separate the user-name 
and password into another file so that when the hook is 
called by whichever admin their corresponding email user-name and password 
will set for AdminAuth and pswd.

```
API data will send
[APItype] => UpdateSend
[Date/Time] => 2016-01-10 00:00:00 
[initit_by] => John_admin
[NewList] => 1
[contact] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0001
        [email] => Patron-email@test.com
        [first_name] => Patron
        [last_name] => t=Test
    )
```

PHP Webhook

```
include_once 'EmailScript.php';

$AdminAuth; 
$pswd;

//This section below is what I want to be more secure
// and called from another file to process the request rather than having it 
// in the webhook.
if(initit_by == John_admin) 
    $AdminAuth = John_admin1@testing.com;
    $pswd = '12345';
if(initit_by == Carry_admin)    
    $AdminAuth = Carry_admin2@testing.com
    $pswd = '54321';

$email = ["contact"]["email"] ;
$emailText = 'Automated Message Received';

$spocket = new EmailScript($AdminAuth, $pswd);
    $send = $spocket->sendEmail($email, $emailText);
    $send = json_decode($send,true);

    if($send['ok'] == true){ 
        echo 'email sent';
    } else{
       echo 'Error!';}
```

Comment: You could use API keys associated with the user?

Comment: Put the admin credentials in a database table.